# Based on which field can be filtered in Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

This code with `id` is accepted:

```
router.post([Page].self, at: "/fetchStatusOfManagedReleases") { (req, pages) -> Future<[Page]> in
    let eventIds = pages.map { $0.events }.flatMap { $0 }.map { $0.id }
    return Release.query(on: req).filter(\.fbId ~~ eventIds).all().flatMap { releases in
        let releaseInnerIds = releases.map {$0.id}

        return TestPrice.query(on: req).filter(\.id ~~ releaseInnerIds).all().flatMap { testPrices in
            return req.future([])
        }
```

but this here with `releaseId` is not:

```
router.post([Page].self, at: "/fetchStatusOfManagedReleases") { (req, pages) -> Future<[Page]> in
    let eventIds = pages.map { $0.events }.flatMap { $0 }.map { $0.id }
    return Release.query(on: req).filter(\.fbId ~~ eventIds).all().flatMap { releases in
        let releaseInnerIds = releases.map {$0.id}

        return TestPrice.query(on: req).filter(\.releaseId ~~ releaseInnerIds).all().flatMap { testPrices in
            return req.future([])
        }
```

TestPrice model:

```
final class TestPrice: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var price: String
    var releaseId: Release.ID

    init(id: Int?, price: String, releaseId: Release.ID) {
        self.id = id
        self.price = price
        self.releaseId = releaseId
    }
}
```

Why? What workaround I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly putting `\TestPrice.releaseId`?

Comment: yes, explicitly :)

Comment: Have you done a `vapor update` lately? As recently as 3 Oct, work was being done on this operator, it seems.

Comment: I got the same error yesterday and it was a consequential error; the real error was elsewhere, but didn't show up until I removed the `.filter(...)` component. Fixing that and reinstating the unchanged filter resulted in it working.